# Excel 2010 VBA - check if slicer value exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet looking at multiple different details of an organisation. All fields are different in the different datasets apart from 'costcentre' which is present in all datasets.

each dataset has its own set of pivot tables and slicers. I am looking to make the costcentre slicer for each table match a chosen slicer.

I have made it work when both slicers have the same values but when the slicer being changed does not have the value of the chosen slicer it is selecting all values. Therefore I am trying to get it to check if a value exists before changing its state and getting it to move onto the next one if it does not (multiple values can be selected) but I cannot find a way of simply checking if a value exists and if not then move on to the next value in the for each bit of the code. Any advice on how to do that or a simpler way of achieving the original goal would be much appreciated

Below is my VBA code. Please note I don't actually have any experience of VBA, this has been constructed from searching for answers on this site and copying bits that seemed relevant with a little bit of trial and error thrown in.

```
Sub test()
Dim sc1 As SlicerCache
Dim sc2 As SlicerCache
Dim si1 As SlicerItem
Dim si2 As SlicerItem

Set sc1 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_CC1")
Set sc2 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_CC")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

sc2.ClearManualFilter



For Each si1 In sc1.SlicerItems
        sc2.SlicerItems(si1.Name).Selected = si1.Selected
        On Error Resume Next
Next si1


    MsgBox "Update Complete"

clean_up:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub

err_handle:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume clean_up
End Sub
```

Comment: Slicers can be connected to multiple pivot tables as long as they share a PivotCache. Since each set of PivotTables are based on a different Dataset, the PivotCaches will be different. If there are values that occur in one PivotCache, but not in the other, in the CostCentre field, you'll run into trouble.
N.b. if you have access to / can use PowerPivot, that would instantly solve your problem, since there you can link the datasets.

Comment: Indeed when I originally took on the task my plan hinged on power pivots, however it turns out our IT support function has removed the add in (all add ins, not just some random vendetta against power pivots!) and are unwilling to re-install any of them. Therefore my need to delve into the world of VBA which I know very little about :-)

Comment: If an item exists in the Slicer you wish to update, but not in the Slicer that was initially set (e.g. where you want to sync from), should that item be selected? And what if there's no items that are the same at all?

Comment: Im trying to think of a suitable analogy - 

dataset 1 lists all rooms in a house, each room can have multiple rows as each one lists a past or present occupant (for the sake of the example all rooms in the house have had at least 1 occupant)

dataset 2 lists all the furniture in the rooms. a room can have multiple rows for multiple bits of furniture however not every room has any furniture.

the slicer in this analogy would be on room number. as such all room numbers appearing in the slicer for dataset 2 are guaranteed to be in the slicer for dataset 1 but not the other way around

Comment: as such if on the primary slider I selected a room number not in the second dataset i would expect that pivot to not show any results. Thankyou for talking through it, apologies if I am not doing a good job of explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters: Altering the part with the loop as follows will not generate errors. If the item from slicer1 exists in the one you are updating, it will take the selection from the first slicer based on the name.

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each si1 In sc1.SlicerItems
   Set si2 = sc2.SlicerItems(si1.Name)
   If Not si2 Is Nothing Then
        si2.Selected = si1.Selected
    End If
Next si1
On Error GoTo 0
```

However, items that are in the second slicer that aren't available in the first one, will be selected no matter what in this scenario, since you cleared the initial selection using `sc2.ClearManualFilter`

If you wish to invert that behaviour, use:

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each si2 In sc2.SlicerItems
    Set si1 = sc1.SlicerItems(si2.Name)
    If Not si1 Is Nothing Then
        si2.Selected = si1.Selected
    Else
        si2.Selected = False
    End If
Next si2
On Error GoTo 0
```

In this case, if nothing is selected in the second slicer (since there are no matching items), no filter will be applied (select all).

Of course you can also leave out the `sc2.ClearManualFilter` line: That way you will only trigger each item to be equal to slicer1 with the first option above. The rest of the selection will then stay as it was before the script was executed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome, that has worked, nice and simple logic too thankyou very much!

Comment: Is there a way to make selections in sc2 match what's selected from sc1, rather than (from appearances) loop and match all in sc2 that exist in sc1? So If i click an item (or multiple items) from sc1, sc2 would reflect the same selections where a match exists?

Comment: @bs0d No, not immediate; there's no array of only selected items available or anything like that. The answer is based on the fact that the two slicers don't share the same SlicerCache. If they do, the change is reflected automatically anyway.

Comment: It's likely beyond the scope of this question, but you can in fact capture an array of selected slicer items and subsequently use that array to filter other tables as desired - all through VBA. The caveat being, you have one master slicer, and other slicers would not be necessary.

Comment: It is. However that array isn't available by default as far as I'm aware. Even if there is a SelectedItems, you can't just pass is to another slicer cache like that. Manually building the array will save some looping on SC2 only.